# How to send PUT/POST request from the same form?

Tags: angular

I have a form. When user doesn't have any information, then he enters in some info and sends a POST request to save the his data. When user has info about himself, that page displays his information and form submit should send a PUT request to update the data.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Mmm the problem stated is weird because if a user is browsing his page, how come he doesn't have information? He should have information even if blank. My point is that the method maybe should always be PUT, but im nitpicking. That aside, maybe it's viable to change the form `method` programmatically?

Comment: @JSelser Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let you are having a profile form:

```
  profilebuilder() {
     this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'email': ['', [Validators.required],
        'firstName': ['', [Validators.required]],
    }
```

and using Get method for getting user data:

```
  getprofile() {
    let url = this.global_service.base_path + 'something...';
    this.global_service.GetRequestAuthorised(url)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.Userinfo = res[0].json.data;
        this.setFormValue();
      },
      err => {
        console.log("data not found");
      },
      () => {

      })
  }
```

call the setformvalue() which will automaticall update your form if user data is there :

```
    setFormValue() {
       this.profileForm.controls['email'].setValue(this.Userinfo.email);
       this.profileForm.controls['firstName'].setValue(this.Userinfo.firstName);
        }
```

then use the PUT request to update your form:

```
  saveprofile(formdata) {
    let url = this.global_service.base_path + 'something...';

    this.global_service.PutRequest(url, formdata)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res[0].status == 200) {
          this.getprofile();
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err, '  error');
      },
      () => {

      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable to mark whether the server has data for the current user. When user sends info, check the variable to determin whether to use POST or PUT.